# How to connect php client to java webservice?

Tags: java, php, web-services

I know php webservice SOAP,json,rest etc, but I am new for java webservice. Now I want to get php client to java webservice.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing new in it. Just create SoapClient with java web services WSDL URL and call it's method:

```
<?php
try{
    $proxy = new SoapClient("javaWsdlUrl?wsdl");
    $result = $proxy->javaWSMethod(array("arg0"=>"1234","arg1"=>"5678"));
    print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage ();
}
?>
```

Other things will be same like generating stubs, getting method names,...

Answer (score 0):

When you connnect to a public webservice like Amazon, you dont (necesserly) know what language is used to create the webservice (server side) . So you will connect to your java webservice the same way you connect to a php or any other webservice.